# Is Julia's `hash()` function guaranteed to have a stable output across sessions, platforms and versions?

Tags: julia

I tried running the following code in multiple different Julia REPL sessions, on MacOSX and Linux, and I always got the exact same outputs:

```
julia> hash(123), hash("123"), hash([1,2,3]), hash((1,2,3)), hash(Set([1,2,3])), hash(:123)
(0x54657e9dbfd649e5, 0xb4e92987fa06fcab, 0xecc5186e7be222c6, 0xafc764e9c2b7cde5, 0x66406071c4c9b92a,
0x54657e9dbfd649e5)
```

**Question: is this behavior guaranteed by the language? Or can the outputs vary (like they do in Python, across sessions, platforms and versions)?**

Note: this question is related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461860/is-the-order-of-julia-sets-and-dicts-guaranteed-to-be-stable-across-sessions-pl) about the stability of the order of hash-based collections such as `Set` and `Dict` (it's closely related, but different).

Comment: Not sure what the current state of this is, but see [this thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/persistent-hash-of-julia-object/1513/7) from 2017. In particular, there are no guarantees across Julia versions or system architecture (32 vs 64 bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not stable and can change from version to version or platforms. They are already different between systems with different word sizes.